# ethernet adapter breaks in vmware guest "windows 2003" from time to time

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-server

This is a windows server 2003 guest (the host is also winodws server 2003) using vmware 1.0.6.

From time to time the guest looses it's ethernet adapter permamently. When I ping from inside the guest I receive "hardware error". I can deactivate and then activate again the ethernet adapter in the windows device manager and that repairs it.

Also when I restart the vm it works again.

But after approx. 1 or 2 weeks the same thing happens again.

Any ideas?

**edit 1:** I do not have VMWare tools installed in the client. Should I?

**edit 2:** I accepted the answer about upgrading, and tried it out

**edit 3:** The upgrade if VMWare server did not help. If anyone has still different approaches which is more specific aboute the symptoms I could also change the accepted answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of VMWare Server 1.0 is 1.0.9; you should really upgrade to it, if you don't want to go all the way to VMWare Server 2.0 (which I dislike, too).

Going from 1.0.6 to 1.0.9 won't impact the way you use the product and it won't force you to learn a completely new UI like going to 2.0 would... but it will solve many nasty bugs, probably including the one you're experiencing.

After upgrading VMWare Server on the host, remember to upgrade the VMWare Tools in the guest systems.